# Reassignment to a val in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I am doing a training exercise in Scala and getting this val reassignment error. I don't see where I am reassigning a new value to a val

```
class personTest
{
  val alf = Person("Alf", 30, List(EmailAddress("alf.kristian@gmail.com")))
  val fredrik = Person("Fredrik", 33, List(EmailAddress("fredrik@vraalsen.no"), EmailAddress("fvr@knowit.no")))
  val johannes = Person("Johannes", 0, Nil)

  val persons = List(alf, fredrik, johannes)

   @Test
  def testNameToEmailAddress
  {
    // Create a map from each persons name to their e-mail addresses,
    // filtering out persons without e-mail addresses
    // Hint: First filter list, then use foldLeft to accumulate...
    val emptyMap: Map[String, List[EmailAddress]] = Map()

    val nameToEmail = persons.filter(_.emailAddresses.length>0).foldLeft(emptyMap)((b,p)=> b+=p.name->p.emailAddresses)

    assertEquals(Map(alf.name -> alf.emailAddresses, fredrik.name -> fredrik.emailAddresses), nameToEmail)
  }

}
```

and I am getting this error

```
error: reassignment to val
val nameToEmail = persons.filter(_.emailAddresses.length>0).foldLeft(emptyMap)((b,p)=> b+=p.name->p.emailAddresses)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`b` which is the name of a parameter to your closure is itself a `val`, which cannot be reassigned.

`foldLeft` works by taking passing the return value of one invocation of the closure as the parameter `b` to the next, so all you need to do is return `b + (p.name->p.emailAddresses)`. (Don't forget the parentheses for precedence.)

Answer (score 3):

You're reassigning val `b` in the expression `b+=p.name->p.emailAddresses`.

Answer (score 3):

Immutable `Map` does not have a `+=` method. In such case, compiler translates `b += p.name -> p.emailAddresses` to `b = b + p.name->p.emailAddresses`. There you have it, **reassignment!**

Comment: Thank You, I changed the map to a mutable map and it worked. Not sure if that is the right solution though

Comment: No need to use a mutable map. You should change `+=` to `+` instead (as already suggested by @Ken Bloom).

Answer (score 0):

As previously mentioned, the error message is originating in the expression `...b+=bp.name...`

But really, you don't need to be doing a foldLeft here at all, a simple mapping should be enough.  Any `Seq[K->V]` can then be converted to a `Map[K,V]` via the `toMap` method.

Something like this:

*disclaimer: not tested for typos, etc.*

```
class personTest {
  val alf = Person(
    "Alf",
    30,
    EmailAddress("alf.kristian@gmail.com") ::
    Nil
  )

  val fredrik = Person(
    "Fredrik",
    33,
    EmailAddress("fredrik@vraalsen.no") ::
    EmailAddress("fvr@knowit.no") ::
    Nil)

  val johannes = Person(
    "Johannes",
    0,
    Nil)

  val persons = List(alf, fredrik, johannes)

  @Test
  def testNameToEmailAddress {

    val nameToEmailMap =
      persons.view filter (!_.emailAddresses.isEmpty) map {
        p => p.name -> p.emailAddresses
      } toMap

    assertEquals(
      Map(
        alf.name -> alf.emailAddresses,
        fredrik.name -> fredrik.emailAddresses
      ),
      nameToEmailMap
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Defining an implicit conversion from `String` to `EmailAddress` seems like an overkill. :)

Comment: True, but the code was *sooooo* boilerplatey, and wide, for trying to fit into the StackOverflow window

Comment: I like the DPP quote (from his book): "I think of implicits like I think of vampires. They are very powerful and very dangerous, and I only invite them into my program's scope when there is a very good reason."

Comment: Used in a properly constrained scope I think implicits are perfectly safe, especially implicit conversions from types used in lieu of dynamic typing.  An implicit conversion here is basically stating that "I can supply a String whenever an EmailAddress is expected", which seems like a reasonable kind of statement.  You drop the boilerplate of all those constructors, but still wrangle things into type-safety ASAP.